# Generic interface with index-type property and method

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

Is there a way in TypeScript to declare the following interface using [index types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types) and *exactly one generic type*, where `map` method would accept value of the same type as `T`'s key instead of `any`?

```
interface Foo<T> {
    key: keyof T;
    map: (value: any) => any;
}
```

Again, the interface needs to accept only one generic type. The following is a possible solution, but does't solve this problem since takes two generic types:

```
interface Foo<T, K extends keyof T> {
    key: K;
    map: (value: T[K]) => any;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a mapped type to generate a union of all combinations of `key`/`map` possibilities. This union will enforce the constraint that the parameter to `map` will be the same type as `T[K]` and contextual typing will also work as expected:

```
type Test = {
  a: string;
  b: number;
}

type Foo<T> = { 
  [P in keyof T]: {
      key: P;
      map: (value: T[P]) => any;
  }
}[keyof T]

let o: Foo<Test> =  {
  key: "a", 
  map: v => v.toLocaleLowerCase() // v is string
};

let o2: Foo<Test> =  {
  key: "b", 
  map: v => v.toLocaleLowerCase() // v is number, so err
};
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwoF4oG8BQUoEMBcUiATgJYB2A5gNxZQBGBZArgLZ0RE0C+GGokUAGIB7YQB4YAPhTootANoAFKOSgBrCCGEAzWAF0CmbMfWaCimiewscYAgAoAbjgA2TCARhK9AShTScMhBLKB4ueQ0tXRg9XhcIJGECEXE4RGlUdFpIggAiHFyAGjlrWwJHfyhHADpgYQAZYQBjVwhGgHcOAGEceAh7PwB6QaqVeEJgUkoMLhoMeMSAJmTRCQRgDOwjUxA8uiKSqBs7UeRpGrrGlviO7t7+oZGKknHmNg5i+GEoDiIZqiAA)

Comment: This. Is. Crazy. 

Comment: This is insane!!